# MS Word: Selecting specific rows across multiple tables

Tags: vba, ms-word

The macro below successfully highlights a specific range of rows from one table. However, I have about 600+ tables to edit. Therefore, I need to find a way to modify this macro somehow, so that it highlights the same range of rows across all tables. I've been experimenting all day, slapping on bits of code here and there, but to no avail. Any help/suggestions would be greatly, greatly appreciated.

```
  Sub cellSel()
    Dim myCells As Range
    With ActiveDocument
      Set myCells = .Range(Start:=.Tables(1).Cell(4, 1).Range.Start, _
        End:=.Tables(1).Cell(15, 12).Range.End)
      myCells.Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a For...Next loop to go from table to table in a document. For example:

```
Sub cellSel()
  Dim myCells As Range
  Dim tbls as Word.Tables, tbl as Word.Table
  Dim doc as Word.Document

  Set doc = ActiveDocument
  Set tbls = doc.Tables
  For Each tbl in tbls
    Set myCells = doc.Range(Start:= tbl.Cell(4, 1).Range.Start, _
      End:=tbl.Cell(15, 12).Range.End)
    myCells.Select
  Next
End Sub
```